# How do I find elements that are not common in Lists using prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have two lists

```
[a,b,c,d]
[c,d]
```

How would I implement a predicate what would return the list below

```
[a,b]
```

in Prolog.

Newbie to prolog. Finding it hard wrapping my head around recursion.

Comment: Some prologs have a readily available predicate `subtract`/3. I think it's highly unlikely this has not been asked before, too

Comment: @vmg: `subtract/3` is probably not what OP asks for:  `[a,b,c,d]` and `[c,d,e]` should probably give `[a,b,e]` and not `[a,b]`.